# MVC 5 - fullcalendar events from model array not rendering in mobile

Tags: .net, mobile, fullcalendar, emulation

The following code works perfectly in IE, but it does not render the calendar in Windows emulator:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            theme: false,
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next',
                center: 'title',
                right: '',
            },
            defaultDate: '2016-01-12',
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            events: 
               [
                       @{var lastItem = Model.eventsArray.Last(); }
                       @foreach (var item in Model.eventsArray) {
                            @:{
                            @: title: ('@item.title.ToString()'),
                            @: start: ('@item.start.ToString()'),
                            @:}

                            if (item != lastItem) {
                               @:, 
                            }
                            else
                            {
                               @:
                            }
                       }
                ]
```